# POST request and get response in order (NodeJS, python client)

Tags: python, node.js, promise

I have a Node.js server continuously receiving python client's POST request to call a backend service. Promise is used in Node server's REST router to call the backend service and then return the results to the client.

On node.js:

```
 router.post("/result/", jsonParser, function (req, res) {
   callService(req.body)
     .then(function(result) {
        res.json({
          result: result
        });
     }, function (error) {
        res.status(400);
     });
 }

 var callService = function(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      //do something;
      resolve(result);
    }
 }
```

The client is sending request messages in order (e.g. reading a file line by line) and saving results in another file line by line.

In client.py:

```
for line in read_file:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        start_new_thread(request_to_server_and_write_to_file, (line))
```

However since the backend processing speed varies due to the complexity of each request message, the result returned to the client **are not in the same order** as the requests sent.

What should I do to make this result in the same order as the requests?

Answer (score 0):

this is a typical case of async programming for which Python is not very well equipped. Luckily there is the asyncio library. If you install that, you can call your function with async await pattern. That way you will be able to await server results before calling new one.

Here is a good explanation:
https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/07/26/python-3-an-intro-to-asyncio/